# How to unlock my device after blocking with "Find my device"?

Tags: locked-out

I lost my phone in a taxi and blocked it using [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/find?u=0). I managed to get it back but now it has a button to call my home and a lock icon, but won't unlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must restart your phone. Turn it off. When you turn it on again you'll be able to enter your password.

**Update**: after doing this, it will lock again. You must really login again using your account in "Find my Device". The option is somewhat hidden in the suspension points button. See:
[image: Where to click to login again: suspension points]

Maybe you don't need to restart your phone after login in "Finde My Device". The restart allows you to enter your device with your password, but sometime latter it will be blocked again. You must really go to the "Find My Device" web page.

Comment: Do you need to go to the Find My Device webpage on the mobile itself or the computer? Regardless, neither of these methods stop the notifications from coming.

Comment: I cleared the storage on my Google Play Services app and that seemed to fix it (clear storage not clear cache).

Comment: @kennyB I used Find My Device webpage from my desktop computer

Answer (score 0):

I saw text message notifications on my screen. All I did was tap it and it then prompted me for my phone access password. I entered the password and my phone opened up as per normal. It was just chance I tried this after having no success in the Find My Device app. 
The suggestion above about turning the phone off and on again could work if it then prompts you for your password. If you have no password not sure what wold happen. Worth a try!

This worked for me! How good is Find My Device. I left my Samsung phone on a bus from Mt Buller to Mansfield at night. I think it fell out of my pocket when I changed seats in the dark!  googled Find my Device on my home PC once I got home (when I realised i did not have it after driving from Mansfield to Melb)). OMG!   I could see on the location map it had gone back up the mountain to Buller late at night. I locked it and left my email address and husband's phone number to call. The bus driver called the number which appeared on my phone screen to call. Lucky for me a friend was catching a bus down the mountain the next day. I organised for the bus line to give it to her and to ask her for ID so no one else could claim it. They called her to arrange it. Thank you MMBL bus lines and shuttle service! I now have back my phone all intact. I felt happy as soon as I could locate it and lock it at least knowing that no one cold use it and I had a chance of getting it back if it fell in the right hands! I would have even driven up there again just to get it or have someone post it as registered mail and reimburse them or I think you get get reverse charge post so you pay when pick it up from a post office. 
If you have no messages try asking someone to send a text message to see if it appears on your screen then tap it open. The you can access the messages if you put in your password and the phone will open up as normal and you can then access everything.

Tip: "Location" must be turned 'on' on your phone for Find My Device to work. You can do this in the pull down screen. If lost google "android device manager" or "find my device" from a pc or someone else's device. When you see your phone located on the map take a photo or screenshot of your pc screen with someone else's phone and that photo showing it's location could be sent to someone else to help locate it, even the police, if someone has stolen your device.